# Simulation timing in gazebo?

Tags: gazebo, physics, gazebo-7

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have set the following condition in my world file. I want real time factor to be 1 so that both simulation and real time run at same speed. But when I launch the world file, real time factor decrease to 0.2 on gazebo screen.

```
<physics type='ode'>
      <max_step_size>0.001000</max_step_size>
      <real_time_factor>1.000000</real_time_factor>
      <real_time_update_rate>1000.000000</real_time_update_rate>
      <gravity>0.000000 0.000000 -9.800000</gravity>
    </physics>
```

Does this mean that gazebo is not able to do the calculations, because of which it is reducing the real time factor, or is there any other reason ?

PS :- Gazebo : 7.13.1 and Ubuntu : 16.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20384/simulation-timing-in-gazebo-?/) by [pk](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5254/pk/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-09-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

> Does this mean that gazebo is not able
> to do the calculations, because of
> which it is reducing the real time
> factor

Correct. If the real time factor drops below your set value then it means Gazebo is having trouble keeping up with the calculations.

---

Originally posted by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) with karma: 376 on 2018-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0